# Construction of flags in R CMD SHLIB

Tags: r, rcpp

I am having a lot of trouble understanding the steps that construct the compilation flags when using `R CMD SHLIB`. I use the following:

- in `~/.R/Makevars` define `CPPFLAGS=-O3'
- in `src/Makevars.win` define `PKG_CPPFLAGS = -O3`
- include Rcpp and RcppGSL as dependencies in the DESCRIPTION file

where the second step is clearly redundant, but I do it just in case `PKG_CXXFLAGS` was initialized to something different.

But when I run `R CMD SHLIB` I find my `-O3` flags but also `-UNDEBUG -Wall -pedantic -g -O0`. Where can those additional flags be coming from? Can Rcpp and RcppGSL affect these flags in a way I can't control through my Makevars.in?

Comment: in the end I am just writing the Makefile directly using definitions from the the makeconf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For per-user, or personal settings, I just use `~/.R/Makevars` which will affect all `R CMD SHLIB` or `R CMD COMPILE` calls, including those from Rcpp.

You can also define them in per-project Makefiles, or `src/Makevars`, and besides the per-user files, you can of course edit the system-wide variant (which is where the other values that confused you came from).  See the file `$R_HOME/etc/Makeconf` for the latter.

Lastly, `DESCRIPTION` has nothing to do here.

Comment: but I actually had a look at Makeconf and could not find where 'pedantic' is added for instance.

Comment: I do not know your machine, but on my box `-pedantic` is added via my user-local `Makevars` if and when I want it added.  The machine-wide default has `--O2` from the Debian configuration.